# opencv, cv::Mat to unsigned short *?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an depth image, loaded with opencv into a cv::Mat.

What I need is to pass the data to a function as `unsigned short * depth`

I am doing this:

```
std::string frame1 = "rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk/depth/1305031453";
Mat img1;
img1 = imread(frame1, 0);


cv::Mat mat_ushort1;
frame1.convertTo(mat_ushort1, CV_16UC1);
```

So far (I assume), so good. Now i would like to pass the data to this function:

```
void initModel(unsigned short * depth)
```

But when I do this:

```
initModel(mat_ushort1.ptr());
```

I get:

```
Error (active)      argument of type "uchar *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned short *"
```

What am I missing here? CAN I pass the Mat data in this way?

Thank you.

EDIT:

i have discovered this:

```
unsigned short* dataMat1 = mat_ushort1.ptr<unsigned short>();
```

which works, but gives different results then expected (Compared to using `pangolin` to load the image, which is what i am trying to avoid).

Comment: Just call the function like this: `initModel((unsigned short*) mat_ushort1.data);`

Comment: Thanks! works great.

Comment: @Zindarod It's C++, so I wouldn't suggest C-style casts, that's just poor practice. To be honest, I wouldn't use cast here at all, rather an appropriately parametrized `cv::Mat::ptr`, as the OP notes in his edit.

Comment: I ended up using my edit code, `unsigned short* dataMat1 = mat_ushort1.ptr<unsigned short>();`. It turned out my issue was with `cv::imread`. using `img1 = imread(frame1, -1);` to load the image unchanged has fixed my problem. thank you for your time.

Comment: @DanMašek I agree about C-style casting, I was in a hurry and didn't pay much attention. But why avoid casting? If you look at the source of the parameterized `cv::Mat::ptr`, it's basically casting the pointer to template param. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L939